# Different models of mcp23017 for raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, multiplexer

Im about to order an mcp23017 for getting more pins to my Raspberry Pi.

I got a bit confused. At the place where I order there multiple models of mcp23017. I guess they are about the same, just different manufactures. Or are there any difference between these two:

https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Adafruit/732/?qs=GURawfaeGuDsiwNCtfEn8A%3D%3D
https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Microchip-Technology/MCP23017-E-SP/?qs=usxtMOJb1RyESXZDw7ia5A%3D%3D

I guess not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Microchip** is the actual manufacturer. They are designing and producing these chips.

**Adafruit** is just selling kits for makers. They act as a reseller and increase the price to get some margin on their own.

Comment: yes thanks. thats what I thought. :) then I just buy the cheapest one :)